# How to make a loop in Less

Tags: css, less

I'm trying to achieve a loop for padding.

Example from less.org just modified

```
.generate-pad(10);

.generate-pad(@n, @i: 1) when (@i =< @n) {
  .padd-top-@{i} {
    padding-top: (@i * 100px / @n);
  }
  .generate-pad(@n, (@i + 1));
}
```

outputs the following when its compiled

```
.padd-top-1 {
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.padd-top-2 {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.padd-top-3 {
  padding-top: 30px;
}
.padd-top-4 {
  padding-top: 40px;
}
.padd-top-5 {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.padd-top-6 {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
.padd-top-7 {
  padding-top: 70px;
}
.padd-top-8 {
  padding-top: 80px;
}
.padd-top-9 {
  padding-top: 90px;
}
.padd-top-10 {
  padding-top: 100px;
}
```

but I am trying to replace `.pad-top-@{i}` with a variable so I can call it later. How can I achieve this?

Comment: you want to replace the class them with var, but it will be iterated over - so are you still adding a number to it?

Comment: @inorganik yes, exactly.

Comment: Check the documentation http://lesscss.org/features/#loops-feature

Comment: So just replace it: `.@{your-var}-@{i}`. (though to be honest I don't understand why to generate all these CSS classes then, if you can make it only when such style is really needed right within the mixin you're going to call).

Comment: In other words, I suspect [this](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/7855508ece5923186d5e) is something like what you really need (w/o any loop).